# MySql - Stored procedure with php

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, batch-insert

I have a stored procedure which helps me to insert dummy data in table.

Here is procedure code

```
BEGIN 
            DECLARE batch_query  TEXT;
            DECLARE str  text;

            DECLARE x  INT;
               SET x = 0;
# here insert_records is IN param which hold number of records we need to insert in batch insert 
               WHILE x  < insert_records DO
                    SET  str = CONCAT_WS('',str,"(md5(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 1000))),(FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 1000))),CURDATE()),");
                    SET  x = x + 1; 
               END WHILE;

            SET batch_query=TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM str);
            INSERT INTO test_consumer (`name`,`amount`,`join_date`) 
                VALUES batch_query;

END
```

When I try to create this, I get an error:

[image]

but when I try this

```
SELECT batch_query;
```

instead of batch insert query

its working absolutely fine and if I try to put query resultant in insert query its work like charm.

Help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your store procedure syntax is wrong. please check that syntax

Comment: @VenkateshPanabaka its working fine if I add result of  batch_query in insert query not pass variable as query input.

Comment: To achieve what you need, you should use [13.5 SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).